# Get last modified fields from version history

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-rest-api, version-history

When I look at the version history of an item I can see the last version, modified date and the fields that were modified. If I use the following rest API endpoint

```
_api/web/Lists/getbytitle('ListTitle')/items(##)/versions
```

I get all the fields which is not the desired behavior. I only want to retrieve which fields were changed similar to when looking through the UI. Any Suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below below query :

```
_api/web/Lists/getbytitle('ListTitle')/items(##)/versions? $top=1&$orderby=modified desc
```

Comment: Hi thanks, but at the end i still receive all the fields, not only those that changed. I would like to retrieve only those fields that changed